# How to display $PATH as one directory per line?

Tags: bash, paths

I cannot figure out how to list the various paths in `$PATH` separately so that they look like this:

```
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Each path should be on a separate line please

Comment: What should be printed if your paths contain newlines?

Comment: And [because we can!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96334/export-the-path-variable-line-by-line)

Comment: Cross site duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80151/85039

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can do this with any one of the following commands, which substitutes all occurrences of `:` with new lines `\n`.

`sed`:

```
$ sed 's/:/\n/g' <<< "$PATH"
```

`tr`:

```
$ tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"
```

`python`:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv[1].replace(":","\n"))' "$PATH"
```

Comment: Variation on your python approach: `python -c 'import sys;print sys.argv[1].replace(":","\n")' $PATH  `

Comment: Another Python variation, kinda hacky: `python -c "print r'$PATH'.replace(':', '\n')"` (using a raw string in case of backslashes)

Comment: `tr` worked for me (on mac, btw). Thanks.

Comment: For those, like me, who want to add it to their `.bash_profile`, add it like this: `alias path='tr ":" "\n" <<< "$PATH"'`

Answer (score 93):

Use bash's [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

This replaces all `:` in `$PATH` by a newline (`\n`) and prints the result. The content of `$PATH` remains unchanged.
If you only want to replace the first `:`, remove second slash: `echo -e "${PATH/:/\n}"`

Comment: I think that this is the best solution because it's done in *pure* bash.

Comment: @ryanmjacobs mildly curious: what do you think my solution uses? :D

Comment: please explain how it works.

Comment: What's that kind of operation called? It's similar to sed but it's not sed. What's the name of it so I can search the web for more info about it.

Comment: Follow link (Parameter Expansion) in my answer and scroll down to last second section called: `${parameter/pattern/string}`

Comment: @muru Yeah, I guess your solution also is in *pure* bash :D But it also uses a subshell and modifies the IFS, so I think this one wins for simplicity.

Comment: This is the best answer. It would be a great answer if you also explained what it was doing.

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13: You'll find a short explanation [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600018/how-to-display-the-paths-in-path-separately/600028?noredirect=1#comment837494_600028).

Comment: @Cyrus I read that and it was educational. I'm referring to the StackExchange preference to put the relevant information in the answer, in case the link changes or dies.

Comment: The significance of the second $ eludes me, yet it seems to be necessary. Aren't we simply replacing the : with a \n ?

Comment: @DominicCronin: For the meaning of `$'\n'` see: [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

Comment: This works for me on ZSH: `echo "${PATH//:/\n}"`

Comment: This also works on bash terminal on Windows

Answer (score 31):

Using IFS:

```
(set -f; IFS=:; printf "%s\n" $PATH)
```

`IFS` holds the characters on which bash does splitting, so an `IFS` with `:` makes bash split the expansion of `$PATH` on `:`. `printf` loops the arguments over the format string until arguments are exhausted.
We need to disable globbing (wildcard expansion) using `set -f` so that wildcards in PATH directory names don't get expanded.

Comment: This works correctly with backslashes and spaces!

Comment: Splits also on spaces in bash terminal on Windows

Answer (score 17):

Using `xargs`:

```
xargs -n1 -d: <<< $PATH
```

From [`man xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xargs.1.html)

```
-n max-args
          Use  at  most  max-args  arguments per command line.

 -d delim
          Input  items  are terminated by the specified character.
```

Comment: would variation on this, such as `echo $PATH | xargs -n1 -d: echo` be redundant or it doesn't matter ?

Comment: @Serg `echo $PATH | xargs -n1 -d:`  will do the same thing for you but you will be using one more shell. The first one will evaluate `echo $PATH` and pipe output to next shell to do the rest.

Answer (score 11):

Probably the only way that hasn't been mentioned is the way i've been using it for years:

`echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"`

so, in your .profile or .bash_profile or whatever, you can add:

`alias path='echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"'`

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/600019/216503) mentioned it already..

Comment: Yeah, but I like the suggestion for the alias.

Comment: A tiny variation makes this work in Git Bash for Windows `echo %PATH% | tr ";" "\n"`

Comment: Just... don't use windows.

Answer (score 8):

#### In this answer:

1. C
2. Python
3. Ruby
4. Alternative awk

#### 1. C

Since all the scripting languages have been taken already, I'll go with C. It's quite easy to get environment variables with `get_env()` function ( see [GNU C Library documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html)). The rest is simply character manipulation

```
bash-4.3$ cat get_path.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *path = getenv("PATH");
    int length = strlen(path) -1;
    for(int i=0;i<=length;i++){
        if (path[i] == ':')
            path[i] = '\n';
        printf("%c",path[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
bash-4.3$ gcc get_path.c
bash-4.3$ ./a.out 
/home/xieerqi/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
/opt/microchip/xc16/v1.25/bin
/opt/microchip/xc32/v1.40/bin
/opt/microchip/xc8/v1.35/bin
/home/xieerqi/bin
/home/xieerqi/bin/sh
```

---

#### 2. Python

But also because "why not" , here's alternative python version via command line arguments `sys.argv`

```
python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.argv[1].split(":"))' "$PATH"
```

---

#### 3.  Ruby

Ruby doesn't  come with Ubuntu by default, unlike C compiler and Python interpreter, but if you ever find yourself using it, the solution in Ruby would be this:

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_.split(":")' <<< "$PATH"
```

As suggested by 7stud (Thank you very much !) in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600018/how-to-display-the-paths-in-path-separately/837251#comment1351868_837251), this can also be shortened with

```
ruby -F: -ane 'puts $F' <<<$PATH
```

and [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600018/how-to-display-the-paths-in-path-separately/837251#comment1352021_837251)

```
ruby -0072 -ne 'puts chomp' <<<$PATH
```

#### 4. Alternative awk

We can utilize `split()` function to break down the line read into array, and use `for-each` loop to print out each item on separate line.

```
awk '{split($0,arr,":"); for(var in arr) print arr[var]}' <<< $PATH
```

Comment: Nice ruby example.  `puts` automatically prints the elements of an array on separate lines!  You can also make the switches do the split: `ruby -F: -ane 'puts $F' <<<$PATH`  Explanation: `-F` sets `$;` to the specified character, which is the default separator used by String::split ($; has a default value of nil, which splits on whitespace).  `-a` calls $_.split, where $_ is a line read in using gets()) and assigns the resulting array to `$F`.

Comment: @7stud hey, thanks ! :)  Didn't know of there's `-F` flag - I am just starting out with Ruby, so doing things slightly crude way.

Comment: No, this is obscure stuff. Your one liner is very readable, and clarity should trump brevity every time.

Comment: Hah.  I figured out a shorter one:  `ruby -0072 -ne 'puts chomp' <<<$PATH`.   Explanation: `-0` sets the input record separator(specify a character in octal format; 072 is a colon).  Ruby employs $_  in ways similar to Perl.   The gets() method (used in the `-n` loop) sets $_ to the current _line_ that's read in.  And `chomp()` without an arg, chomps $_.  I still like yours better. :)

Comment: @7stud actually, the one you posted earlier, with `-F` flag, is shorter. If you do `echo "ruby -F: -ane  'puts $F' <<<$PATH" |wc -c ` that tells me it's 271, bytes, but the one with octal number is 276. That's for the whole command, of course,  If we consider only the code itself  `puts $F` is clearly shorter.  :) By the way , do you know about [codegolf.se] ?  It's the site for solutions to programming puzzles in shortest number of bytes.   There's a question related to this one : http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96334/55572

Comment: Thanks.  The one over there looks the shortest and clearest: `ruby -e 'puts ENV["PATH"].split /:/'.  I studied Perl for awhile, and the code golf they play is unreal.  I saw one where the code had to be written so it read like a poem.  Ah, its [here](https://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol5_1/tpj0501-0012.html).

Answer (score 7):

Here's the equivalent in Go:

```
$ cat path.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    for _, p := range strings.Split(os.Getenv("PATH"), ":") {
        fmt.Println(p)
    }
}

$ go run path.go
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
/home/nathan/.local/bin
/home/nathan/go/bin
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few more approaches. I'm using a `PATH` with directories containing backslashes, spaces and even a new line to show that they should work with anything (except the `cut` one which fails on newlines):

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/bin:usr/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/some\ horrible thing:/even 
new lines
```

- Some Perl ways:

  ```
  $ perl -pe 's/:/\n/g' <<<"$PATH"
  /bin
  usr/bin/
  /usr/local/bin
  /some\ horrible thing
  /even 
  new lines
  ```

  The `-p` means "print every input line after applying the script given by `-e`". The script is using the substitution operator (`s/oldnew/`) to replace all `:` with newlines.

  ```
  $ perl -lne 'print for split /:/' <<<"$PATH"
  /bin
  usr/bin/
  /usr/local/bin
  /some\ horrible thing
  /even 
  new lines
  ```

  The `-l` adds a newline to each `print` call. Here, the script is splitting its input on `:` and then loops over each split element and prints it.

  ```
  $ perl -F: -ane '$"="\n";print "@F"' <<<"$PATH"
  /bin
  usr/bin/
  /usr/local/bin
  /some\ horrible thing
  /even 
  new lines
  ```

  The `-a` makes `perl` behave like `awk`: it will split each of its input lines on the character given by `-F` (so `:`, here) and save the result in the array `@F`. The `$"` is a special Perl variable, the "list separator", whose value is printed between each element of a printed list. So setting it to a newline will make `print @list` print each element of `@list` and then a newline. Here, we're using it to print `@F`.

  ```
  $ perl -F: -ane 'print join "\n", @F' <<<"$PATH"
  /bin
  usr/bin/
  /usr/local/bin
  /some\ horrible thing
  /even 
  new lines
  ```

  Same idea as above, just less golfed. Instead of using `$"`, we are explicitly `join`ing the array with newlines and then printing.
- Simple `grep` with PCRE magic:

  ```
  $ grep -oP '(^|:)\K[^:]+' <<<"$PATH"
  /bin
  usr/bin/
  /usr/local/bin
  /some\ horrible thing
  /even 
  new lines
  ```

  The `-o` makes `grep` print only the matching portion of each line, so each match is printed on a separate line. The `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE). The regex is looking for stretches of non-`:` (`[^:]+`) that follow either the beginning of the line (`^`) or a `:` character. The `\K` is a PCRE trick that means "discard anything matched before this point" and is used here to avoid printing the `:` as well.
- And a `cut` solution (this one fails on newlines, but can deal with backslashes and spaces):

  ```
  $ cut -d: -f 1- --output-delimiter=$'\n' <<<"$PATH"
  /bin
  usr/bin/
  /usr/local/bin
  /some\ horrible thing
  /even 
  new lines
  ```

  The options used are `-d:` which sets the input delimiter to `:`, `-f 1-` which means print all fields (from the 1st to the end) and `--output-delimiter=$'\n'` which sets the, well, output delimiter. The `$'\n'` is [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) and is a way to print a newline character in the shell.

In all of the above examples, I am using bash's (and some other shells') [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) (`<<<`) operator to pass a string as input to a program. So `command <<<"foo"` is equivalent to `echo -n "foo" | command`. Note that I am always quoting `"$PATH"`, without the quotes, the shell would have eaten the newline character.

---

[@7stud](https://askubuntu.com/users/642093/7stud) gave another approach in [the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600018/how-to-display-the-paths-in-path-separately/837404#comment1351878_837404) that's just too good not to include:

```
$ perl -0x3a -l012 -pe '' <<<"$PATH"
```

That's what's known as [golfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf). The `-0` specifies the input record separator as an octal or hexadecimal number. This is what defines a "line" and its default value is `\n`, a newline character. Here, we're setting it to a `:` which is `x3a` in hex (try `printf '\x3a\n'`). The `-l` does three things. First it removes the input record separator (`$/`) from the end of each line—effectively removing the `:` here—and second, it sets the output record separator (`$\`) to whatever octal or hex value it is given (`012` is `\n`). If `$\` is defined, it is added to the end of each `print` call, so this will result in a newline appended to each `print`.

The `-pe` will **p**rint each input line after applying the script given by `-e`. Here there is no script because all the work is done by the option flags as described above!

Comment: Your perl one liners are not obscure enough! Here’s a version where there’s no code for the -e switch to execute because the other switches handle everything: `perl -0x3a -l012 -pe '' <<<$PATH`. Explanation: `-0` sets the input record separator (specified in hex/octal notation, x3A is a colon), `-l` does two things: 1) it chomps the input record separator, 2) it sets the output record separator if one is specified (in octal notation, 012 is a newline). A `-p` loop prints out the value of $_ , which will be each _line_ read in.

Comment: Also note that your examples using `-F`can eliminate the `-a` and `-n` flags, as -F turns those on automatically: `perl -F: -e 'print(join "\n", @F);' <<<$PATH`.  See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).  Nice examples.

Comment: @7stud wow, that's really kind of brilliant, thanks! Shamelessly stolen and added to my answer (I assume you don't mind, feel free to post it as an answer yourself and I'll delete it). And thanks for the `-F` info. I've been using `-F` combined with `-an` for years, I never realized the one implied the others. By the way, I saw Serg mentioned [codegolf.se], but I think you'd also enjoy [unix.se] if you're into this sort of thing.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  One clarification about this statement: _Finally, `-l` also adds the output record separator given to the end of each print call._   In fact, print always adds the output record separator, `$/`, to the end of a string--if the output record separator is defined.  By default it is is undef.  So `-l` jus sets `$/`, and that causes print to add the newline to the end of the string.

Comment: _I assume you don't mind_ -- Not at all. :)

Comment: @7stud you mean `$\ `, not `$/` (sorry, couldn't resist :) but yes, you're quite right, thanks.

Comment: Arggh.........:(

Answer (score 5):

We need more Java!

```
public class GetPathByLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String p : System.getenv("PATH").split(":")) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Save this to `GetPathByLine.java`, and compile using:

```
javac GetPathByLine.java
```

Run with:

```
java GetPathByLine
```

---

```
┌─[17:06:55]─[kazwolfe@BlackHawk]
└──> ~ $ cat GetPathByLine.java 
public class GetPathByLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String p : System.getenv("PATH").split(":")) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
┌─[17:06:58]─[kazwolfe@BlackHawk]
└──> ~ $ javac GetPathByLine.java 
┌─[17:07:02]─[kazwolfe@BlackHawk]
└──> ~ $ java GetPathByLine 
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

Comment: Wow this is overkill. You can do this in one line in Python 3: `python3 -c "import os; [print(p) for p in os.getenv('PATH').split(':')]"`

Comment: @wjandrea That's the point! :D

Answer (score 4):

Through awk.

```
echo $PATH | awk -F: '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'
```

Through python.

```
$ echo $PATH | python3 -c 'import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    for i in line.split(":"):
        print(i)'
```

Note that Indentation is very important in python.

Comment: Shorter awk: `echo $PATH | awk '{gsub(/\:/,"\n");print}'`

Comment: I'mm not sure why you bother with `fileinput` when you could just use `input`: `python3 -c 'print(*input().split(":"), sep="\n")' <<< "$PATH"`

Answer (score 2):

I use Stephen Collyer's "Bash Path Functions" (see [his article in Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645)). It permits me to use the "colon separated list" as a datatype in shell programming. For example, I can produce a list of all the directories in the current directory by:

```
dirs="";for i in * ; do if [ -d $i ] ; then addpath -p dirs $i; fi; done
```

Then, `listpath -p dirs` produces a list.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation for @Cyrus answer

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

Notes:

[ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) - it explains $'some\ntext'

[Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) - it explains ${parameter/pattern/string}, If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.

So we have:

1. a pattern **/:** which start with '/' to replace all matches
2. a string **$'\n'** which is quoted with $'anytext' contraction to treat new line symbol (\n).

Answer (score 1):

Another AWK way is to treat each directory as a separate *record*, rather than as a separate *field*.

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{RS=":"} {print $0}' <<<"$PATH"
```

I find that syntax particularly intuitive. But, if you like, you can shorten it by making the `print $0` implicit (it is the default action, and `1` evaluates to true, causing it to be done for every line):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=":"} 1' <<<"$PATH"
```

AWK's default input and output record separator is the newline (line break). By setting the input record separator (`RS`) to `:` before reading the input, AWK automatically parses a colon-deliminated `$PATH` into its constitutent directory names. AWK expands `$0` to each whole record, the newline remains the *output* record separator, and no looping or `gsub` is needed.

```
ek@Io:~$ echo "$PATH"
/home/ek/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
ek@Io:~$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=":"} {print $0}' <<<"$PATH"
/home/ek/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

AWK is often used to parse records into separate fields, but there's no need for that just to construct a list of directory names.

This works even for input containing blanks (spaces and tabs), even multiple consecutive blanks:

```
ek@Io:~$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=":"} {print $0}' <<<$'ab\t\t c:de    fg:h'
ab               c
de    fg
h
```

That is, unless you cause AWK to *rebuild* the record (see below), it's no problem to have spaces or tabs (the default field separators) in the input. Your `PATH` probably doesn't contain spaces on an Ubuntu system, but if it does, this will still work.

---

It's worth mentioning, as a side note, that AWK's ability to interpret a record as a collection of fields *becomes* useful for the related problem of constructing a table of directory *components*:

```
ek@Io:~$ awk -F/ 'BEGIN{RS=":"; OFS="\t"} {$1=$1; print $0}' <<<"$PATH"
        home    ek      bin
        usr     local   sbin
        usr     local   bin
        usr     sbin
        usr     bin
        sbin
        bin
        usr     games
        usr     local   games
        snap    bin
```

The curious `$1=$1` assignment serves the purpose of forcing AWK [to rebuild the record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705660/1038860).

(This is probably more useful for cases where additional processing is to be done on the components, than for the exact example shown of simply printing the table.)

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -Rr 'gsub(":";"\n")' <<<$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

> ### How to display the paths in $PATH separately

These are my preferred ways of doing this based on my respective use-cases and concerns about compatibility and resource usage.

### `tr`

First, if you need a quick, easy to remember, and readable solution, just echo `PATH` and pipe it to [translate (`tr`)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) to turn the colons into newlines:

```
echo $PATH | tr : "\n"
```

It has the downside of using two processes because of the pipe, but if we're just hacking in a terminal, do we really care about that?

### Bash's shell parameter expansion

If you want a fairly permanent solution in your `.bashrc` for interactive use, you can alias the following command to `path`, but the readability of this solution is questionable:

```
alias path="echo \"${PATH//:/$'\n'}\""
```

> If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the first match is replaced.

The above command substitutes the colon with newlines using Bash's [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
```

To explain it:

```
          # v--v---------delimiters, a'la sed
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
          #  ^^ ^^^^^----string, $ required to get newline character.
          #   \----------pattern, / required to substitute for *every* :.
```

Good luck remembering this when you're just hacking on the command line, if you haven't aliased it, though.

### IFS, tested in Bash and Dash

Alternatively, a fairly cross-compatible, readable, and understandable approach that doesn't rely on anything other than the shell is use the following function (I suggest in your `.bashrc`.)

The following function temporarily makes the Internal (or Input) Field Separator (IFS) a colon, and when an array is given to `printf`, it executes until the array is used up:

```
path () {
    local IFS=:
    printf "%s\n" ${PATH}
    }
```

This method of [function creation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05), [`IFS`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), and [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) are provided for by posix, so it should work in most posix-like shells (especially Dash, which Ubuntu usually aliases as `sh`).

### Python

Should you use Python for this? You could. This is the shortest Python command I can think of for this:

```
python -c "print('\n'.join('${PATH}'.split(':')))"
```

or Python 3 only (and perhaps more readable?):

```
python3 -c "print(*'${PATH}'.split(':'), sep='\n')"
```

These should work in any usual shell environment as well, so long as you have Python.

Comment: Is it possible you need to `\$` escape the first `$` dollar sign too? Otherwise I think this does the reformatting only once at load-time, instead of every time you run the path command.

Comment: `alias path="echo \"\${PATH//:/$'\n'}\""` was the command I needed to use.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is simpler than the *Java*, *C*, *go* and *awk* solutions:

```
$ LPATH=$PATH wine cmd /c echo %LPATH::=$'\n'% 2> /dev/null
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
```

Here's another great possibility:

```
$ jrunscript -classpath /usr/share/java/bsh.jar -e 'print(java.lang.System.getenv("PATH").replaceAll(":","\n"))'
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
```

This would require some dependencies to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless bsh
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in **Git Bash** for **Windows**:

```
python -c "import os; print os.environ['PATH'].replace(';', '\n')"
```

It breaks the lines nicely:

```
c:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\MPI-RT\4.1.3.045\ia32\bin
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\vim74
```